# Automaticaly use next row's value in a column of reference table when generating a new sheet

Tags: excel

Is there a formule to automatically shift a value on the "next sheet" to the next line of a reference sheet without having to manually edit that reference, when adding a new "next sheet"?

It's not too much work to manually do this (leave the formula to use the first datum, and then manually edit to show the next cell's value instead, but I have thought of how to fix this challenge without result)

Ie.
sheet2 is created manually, and manually refers to sheet1.a1's value.
when I then create the next sheet (ultimately a copy of the sheet2), ie. when adding a new days' basic sheet, based off the basic day's template (sheet2).

sheet1
a1 displays "one"
a2 displays "two"
a3 displays "three"

sheet2
b5 should display sheet1.a1 (one)

sheet3
b5 should display sheet1.a2 ("two")
(seeing that sheet2 referred to sheet1.a1)

sheet4
b5 should display sheet1.a3 ("three")
(seeing that sheet3 referred to sheet2.a1)

et cetera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each sheet's (except in Sheet1) `B5` cell add formula:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" &SHEET()-1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I did not actually know either indirect() or Sheet()